# Using nested mapping within Observable subscription - Angular6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs

I am fetching some data via an API call (within my dataservicse.ts file) - and the response I get is a sort of complex JSON structure. I am able to fetch a specific part of the response as follows in my corresponding Component file as follows -

Here is one of the JSON object response that represents the general structure -

```
{
    "address": {
        "building": "1234",
        "coord": [0, 0],
        "street": "123 Main Street",
        "zipcode": "00000"
    },
    "address2": "Test Suite 000",
    "grades": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "score": 3
    }, {
        "grade": "B",
        "score": 4
    }, {
        "grade": "A",
        "score": 2
    }],
    "name": "John Doe",
    "_id": "1212121"
}
```

Now - my goal is to acquire the 'name' attribute as well as the first 'grade' value within the grades attribute from each response object - and map them into separate Arrays so that I can display them in table columns using *ngFor.

This is my Component code

```
export class TestDataComponent implements OnInit {

name$: Object;
grade$: Object;

constructor(private data: DataService, private data2: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   //getAPIData is returning the API response from the dataservices.ts file
   this.data.getAPIData().subscribe(
       data=>console.log(data.response.map(name=>name.name))
       ); //this works fine - I get the names in an array

     this.data2.getAPIData().subscribe(
     data2=>console.log((data2.response.map(grade=>grade.grades)).map(grades 
        => {grades.map((value, index) => value.grade})) //this returns an undefined value
  );
 }
```

Now - if I `console.log((data2.response.map(grade=>grade.grades))`
I get an Array of Array objects such as -

```
Array - [Array(3), Array(3), Array(2)]
```

and each of them consist of the 'grades' attribute Array of objects.
(taking the first array from above) -

```
Array(3)
0:{"grade": "A","score": 3}
1:{"grade": "B", "score": 4}
2:{"grade": "A", "score": 2}
```

Thus - I further map my initial response to achieve the 'grade' value. Also - I only want the first grade - thus I have a simple condition added as follows -

```
console.log((data2.response.map(grade=>grade.grades))
              .map(grades 
                  => {grades.map((value, index) =>{if(index<1) value.grade})}))
```

As mentioned in the comment - I get an undefined value.

I undestand this issue may be fairly complex but I've tried my best to explain it as clearly as possible. My goal is to get the first 'grade' values from each object and display them in an Array - just as the names, so that I can use it to display it on a table.

I am fairly new to Angular6, just switching from Angular 1.6 - so I am pretty sure I am messing something up.

What would be the best way to get the grade values into an Array by nested mapping within subscribe? Or is there a better approach to the same ?

Also - for the sake of simplicity, ignore the fact that the first subscription is present (for the name attribute) - I showed it here so as to make it clear as to what I want to achieve.

Comment: From the looks of it, it has nothing to do with the Observable, you are more concerned with how to map your response into a new data structure correct?

Comment: Yes - I was not sure if it was a mapping issue or something wrong with how I'm implementing within 'subscribe' - Not sure why the mapping wouldn't work this way - I tried to separate by storing each mapping to a variable and it seemed to do OK. But I do need it in one go since its within subscribe. Not sure if that makes sense, I could provide more details if need be.

Comment: Are you injecting the same `DataService` twice? Does each call to `getAPIData` return the same JSON object you've posted? And why are you trying to map/reduce values within subscribe instead of using a piped chain of operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I *think* you're asking for since you never gave a concrete example of what you're trying to map/reduce. Also, this is vanilla JavaScript but could easily be translated into RxJS.

```js
// I am assuming that a call to `DataServce.getAPIData()` returns an array
const api_response = [{
    "address": {
        "building": "1234",
        "coord": [0, 0],
        "street": "123 Main Street",
        "zipcode": "00000"
    },
    "address2": "Test Suite 000",
    "grades": [{
        "grade": "A",
        "score": 3
    }, {
        "grade": "B",
        "score": 4
    }, {
        "grade": "A",
        "score": 2
    }],
    "name": "John Doe",
    "_id": "1212121"
}];

// Map and pluck the values you need
const result = api_response.map(v => [v.name, v.grades[0].score])

// Or as an array of objects
const obj_result = result.map(([name, score]) => ({ name, score }))

// Is this what you want?
console.log('Array', result);
console.log('Objects', obj_result);
```

### Quick Update

Thanks for accepting the answer. Just wanted to give a quick of what this might look like using RxJS. I say *might* because the code snippet below is untested.

```
this.nameAndScores$ = data.getAPIData().pipe(
  map(({ response }) => response),
  map(({ name, grades }) => ( { name, score: grades[0].score } ))
)
```

Assuming that `nameAndScores$` is a property of your component instance, you can do `*ngFor item in nameAndScores$ | async` and avoid any explicit subscriptions in your code.

Comment: Yes - you're right - it does return an array. But I'd like to get only the first 'grade' attribute - not the 'score'. Also - can this be done within subscribe without declaring a const - just console.log the mapped result ?

Comment: I'm still not clear what data structure you want back? I've updated the answer to pluck `score` from the nested grades array. With RxJS, you're performing the same logic by "pushing" data through a series of operators instead of "pulling" them through. The `const` you're referring to would be produced in the operator chain and pushed through the stream as opposed to pulling it in for processing within `subscribe`.

Comment: Well this is ALMOST what I wanted - I understand what is being done here but the issue that persists is that I have a lot of data - so the response is an array of array objects [ ["John Doe", 3], ["Jeff Doe", 4], ...]- not sure how I can *ngFor that in a <td> element to get each value display them. If you'd like I can put up a screenshot of what the console shows.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot will help. but even an array of `[[name, score], [name, score], ...]` can easily be mapped to `[{name, score}, {name, score}, ...]`. Is that what you need? Updated again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was totally lost on the Observable concept that I forgot I could do this using vanilla JS - again, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using curly braces with a fat arrow in second map function. While using curly braces, you should return a value using the `return` keyword.

Comment: Do you mean - 
console.log((data2.response.map(grade=>grade.grades)).map(grades => {grades.map((value, index) =>{if(index<1) return value.grade})});

This returns undefined as well.

Comment: can you please add a sample of data2.response